# Did Ron Silver act in "The Thirteenth Floor"?

Tags: the-thirteenth-floor, timecop

Did Ron Silver act in "The Thirteenth Floor"? I think he did a role as a jury in the scene of the dance contest. I´m talking about the same actor in Timecop.

Comment: IMDB says no. Care to add a screenshot?

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 4):

IMDB says [no](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0798779/).

Now, admittedly Ron Silver could have taken time out from his busy filming schedule at the end of 1998 to do a small uncredited cameo role in a low-budget sci-fi film as a favour to a Director to whom he has no obvious connections but it seems unlikely. Also, none of the judges look like him.

[image]

Comment: *"Also, none of the judges look like him."* Oh come on. The black woman is his spitting image! Add some glasses/earrings and - Presto! ;)

Comment: @andrewthompson - I was thinking that, but the nose is all wrong

Comment: I think he could be the second beging from the right, between the to women.